# Prove that $Var(E[Y|\mathcal{G}) \leq Var(Y)$ for $Y$ random variable square integrable

Tags: probability-theory

This is what I came out so far ($Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$ medible):

$$Var(Y) = E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2$$
$$Var(E[Y|\mathcal{G}]) = E[E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^2] - E[E[Y|\mathcal{G}]]^2$$
$$Var(E[Y|\mathcal{G}]) = E[E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^2] - E[Y]^2$$

So, to prove the inequality I have to prove that:

$$E[E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^2] \leq E[Y^2]$$
$$\int_{\Omega}E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^2dP \leq \int_{\Omega}Y^2dP$$
$$\int_{\Omega}E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^2dP - \int_{\Omega}Y^2dP \leq 0$$
$$\int_{\Omega}(E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^2 - Y^2) dP \leq 0$$

This is where I'm stuck. if I had $\int_{\Omega}(E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^2 - Y^2) dP = 0$ it follows that $E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^2 - Y^2 = 0$ almost surely.

But if I have:
$$\int_{\Omega}(E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^2 - Y^2) dP \leq 0$$
I'm not sure if it holds that $(E[Y|\mathcal{G}]^2 - Y^2) \leq 0$ almost surely.

Comment: We have $V(Y) = E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2$ and $V[E(Y|G)] = E[E(Y|G)^2] - E(Y)^2$. Note that $$V(Y) - V[E(Y|G)] = E(Y^2)- E[E(Y|G)^2]\geq 0.$$ *(The inequality above follows from the Conditional Jensen's Inequality. With $(\varphi(x)=x^2)$ we have $E[Y^2|G] \geq E[Y|G]^2$. Then, by integrating both sides, we get $E[Y^2] \geq E[E(Y|G)^2]$.)*

Comment: Note that $Y=E(Y|G)+Z$ with $E(Y|G)$ and $Z$ orthogonal in the sense that Cov$(E(Y|G),Z)=0$, and deduce that Var$(Y)=$Var$(E(Y|G))+$Var$(Z)$, which implies (and quantifies) the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it thanks to fdhjsak:

I have to prove that:

$$Var(Y) - Var(E(Y|\mathcal{G}) = E(Y^2) - E(E(Y|\mathcal{G})^2) \geq 0$$

The Jensen Inequality says that $\mathcal{f}(E(Y)) \leq E(\mathcal{f}(Y))$. If $\mathcal{f}(x) = x^2$ with $x = Y$ it is concave, so I can apply this inequality:

$$E(Y|\mathcal{G})^2 \leq E(Y^2|\mathcal{G})$$
$$E(E(Y|\mathcal{G})^2) \leq E(E(Y^2|\mathcal{G}))$$
$$E(E(Y|\mathcal{G})^2) \leq E(Y^2)$$

Comment: Actually $Var(Y) - Var(E(Y|\mathcal{G})) = E(Y^2)-E(E(Y|\mathcal{G})^2)$, not the opposite.

Comment: @Did OMG!! you're right! I'm fixing it right now *facepalm*